# carrying form information over to next page Java, REST API

Tags: java, rest

We have an old java web application written using Servlets which we are now converting to REST. One of the modules is to collect user data & preferences over a series of 8 web pages, saving each page, and submitting on the last page. Like this :

pg1-save --> pg2- save --> .... pg8 - submit

From each page, we need to send data to the next page, so that the next page is loaded dynamically based on the preferences set on the previous page

Earlier they used HTTPSession.setAttribute and query params etc. to do this

I am new to REST and stuck on how to achieve this in REST model. Please advise

Comment: How were you persisting the data beforehand?  Was it stored in their session or sent to a database?

Comment: Each page data is saved to the database, and some of the information is set as attributes in the session

Comment: REST is not necessarily exclusive to not using servlets.  I don't think REST will really change anything from your previous efforts.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @TimBiegeleisen here.  I don't see how REST would necessarily interfere with this.